# Can I specify the layout of a vsplit command?

Tags: vim, vi, editors

When I do the `:vsplit` command, it always opens the new file on the left side of the screen. Is there a way I can specify I want the new file to open to the right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for

```
:set splitright
```

You can also influence this for individual commands, e.g.

```
:rightbelow vsplit
```

Comment: I added `set splitright` to my vimrc, thank you!